# ERROR Unexpected aliasing of 'this' to local variable @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, lint, tslint

How do I solve this typescript error?

I'm getting error in the below line.

**const self = this;**

I'm getting error in the terminal like:

**error  Unexpected aliasing of 'this' to local variable  @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias**

Please find the code below:

```
notifyOwner(req, metadata, callback) {
    const currentUserId = req.session.identity.individual.userName;
    const docId = metadata.docId;

    let message = this.templates.selfRemoval;
    const self = this;

    const targetUserId = metadata.ownerId;
    const paperTitle = metadata.title.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '');
    const nonOwnerRole = metadata.userRole;

    message = message.replace(/\[CollaboratorName\]/g, req.session.identity.individual.firstName + ' ' + req.session.identity.individual.lastName);
    message = message.replace(/\[NonOwnerRole\]/g, (nonOwnerRole === 'author') ? 'collaborator' : 'reviewer');
    message = message.replace(/\[PaperTitle\]/g, paperTitle);

    const eventData = {
      message: message,
      objectType: 'manuscript',
      objectId: docId
    };

    self.createEvent(currentUserId, targetUserId, eventData, (err, result) => {
      if (result) {
        const userActivityService = new UserActivityService();
        userActivityService.broadcastRefreshUserEvents(eventData['objectId'], { userId: targetUserId });
      }

      callback(null, JSON.stringify({ notified: true }));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This warning usually exists to get script-writers to utilize arrow functions instead of declaring new variables. For example, this:

```
let that = this;
someFn(function(arg) {
  return that.foo = arg;
});
```

can be simplified to

```
someFn(arg => this.foo = arg);
```

But in your case, you're not even using the reassigned value in any other functions - you're just referencing it directly lower in the code, which makes the assignment completely superfluous.

Just remove your

```
const self = this;
```

and replace

```
self.createEvent(
```

with

```
this.createEvent(
```